# All pictures adjusted automatically to left on blog

Tags: html, django

All pictures adjusted automatically to left on blog
I have created page here: http://dzikuss98.pythonanywhere.com/ using django

As you see all pictures are aligned to left even during creation of post they were in middle
below you can see my blog template:

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}
{% block content %}

    {% for post in object_list %}
    {% autoescape off %}
        <h5>{{ post.date|date:"Y-m-d" }}<a href="{{post.id}}"> <b> {{ post.title }}</b></a></h5>

        {{ post.body|linebreaks|truncatechars:300 }}

    {% endautoescape %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I use WYSIWG editor

Comment: Is there a question? What behavior do you want? What WYSIWYG editor are you using? Your images are just `img` tags dropped between `p` tags, so the current behavior is expected and appropriate.

Comment: Hi, sorry for missed question. I use WYSIWYG editor called: froala_editor. I would like them to appear accordingly to as I set them in editor. If I  put them on left, they should be on left; If I put them in middle they should be in middle etc